Looker : Avoiding code repetition in html parameters in views
I’m working on a looker project that uses legacy tables.
Each column is represented by a dimension in a view, and there is quite a lot of html formatting in each view.
A lot of the formatting logic in that home parameter is repeated throughout the rest of the dimensions, making the view file very long.
In “ordinary programming” this repeated code issue would have e been overcome by writing all that  logic into a function/method and calling said function/method  every time it was needed .
But as far as I have seen looker does not support this functionality.
How have you fixed this issue in the past?
It looks like liquid does not support the creation of functions directly, however workarounds like the one this user has found:
https://github.com/reggi/shopify-liquid-functions  exist
But i don’t think that this workaround works in looker, as one cannot create .liquid files within the editor .

can you provide example of the code you are repeating?

@Korean_Of_the_Mountain  predictably enough, as soon as I posted the comment, I found the answer I had been looking for for days online :) . Leaving the documentation in case someone may need it as well. I wanted to modularise the conditional formatting on html. https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Modeling/Save-color-in-parameter-for-reuse/td-p/569640     You can also pass parameters in the html constants by creating a variable in the actual view, and then utilising that variable name in the constant you define in the manifest
